# Gitconfig error when installing homebrew on macOS

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on my Mac running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4.

When I run the installation command in command line `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` the following error is returned:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: bad config line 1 in file /Users/a/.gitconfig
Failed during: git init -q
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

fatal: bad config line 1 in file /Users/a/.gitconfig
Failed during: git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true
==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of `/Users/a/.gitconfig` as a code block.

Comment: @bk2204 That file does not exist for some reason.

Comment: Did you sanitize the output you provided and it's actually another file?  Git is definitely complaining about the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory, so it clearly must exist.